# What does "differentiate with respect to $g(x)$" actually mean intuitively?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am very confused with questions such as:

\begin{equation*}
\text{Differentiate}~~f(x)=x, ~x\in\mathbb{R}~~\text{with respect to }x^2
\end{equation*}

I have seen solutions for many similar questions, but they always just apply the usual rules for differentiation such as the chain rule. I am still confused on the "actual meaning of this". I always thought of differentiating $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ as

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
\end{equation*}
representing how $f$ changes when $x$ is changed, but how could we determine how $f(x)$ changes based on $x^2$ changing as $x^2$ is not injective? For instance, if we have $x^2 = 16$ initially and we "move it" to $x^2 = 25$, how could we find the corresponding change to $x$ and by extension the change to $f(x)$ if both $x=5$ and $x=-5$ satisfy $x^2=25$? I only understand what this would mean if we restrict the domain for instance to $x\geq 0$ so $x^2$ is injective, and this would clearly represent a change from $x=4$ to $x=5$, and therefore a change of $f(5)-f(4)$ but clearly, this isn't true as we can differentiate $f(x)=x$ with respect to $x^2$, and get that $\dfrac{df}{d(x^2)}=\dfrac{1}{2x}$

Comment: You can think of differentiation with respect to a certain function as a distortion of space.

Comment: So I think what they mean is that they want you to calculate $$( f\circ g^{-1})'(g(x)).$$ By the chain rule (if applicable) this is $$f'(x) (g^{-1})'(g(x)).$$ By the inverse function Theorem (if applicable) this is $$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Comment: But if $g(x)$ is not injective on the domain, then doesn't an inverse not exist? For the derivative of $f(x)=x$ with respect to $x^2$, the derivative is $\frac{1}{2x}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $x^2$ is not invertible

Comment: @chair This is a very good comment. Since taking derivatives is a local issue, it is enough if $g$ is invertible locally. Then the above argument works given suitable differentiability of $f$ and $g$. It doesn't work if $g$ is not invertible locally. For example, $g(x)=x^2$ is locally invertible except at $x=0$, and you also notice that there is a problem there since $\frac{1}{2x}$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: So to differentiate with respect to $g(x)$, it would mean that for each $x$, take a neighbour hood $(x-\delta ,x+\delta )$ around $x$ where $g$ is invertible, and then find the corresponding limit? Would this mean that formally, to find the derivative of $f(x)=x$ with respect to $x^2$, we would need to split this into at least two cases with positive and negative $x$?

Comment: For this problem, the invertibility of $g(x) = x^2$ is a red herring.  It is enough that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^2$ is injective.  This puts the $x$-axis in bijection with $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}x^2$ and with this we (inversely) scale the rate of change of $f$ at $x$ by the rate of change of $x^2$ at the same $x$.  Of course, this also works without the injectivity since repeating a scale factor at two or more different $x$s is perfectly fine.  (In fact, differentiating with respect to $x$, the rate of change of $x$ is constant at all $x$s...)

Comment: @EricTowers How would this work with something else, such as differentiating with respect to $\sin(x)$? Another problem I saw was finding the derivative of $\cos(x)$ with respect to $\sin(x)$, would we then have to consider the approach where it is continuous locally?

Comment: The derivative of $\cos(x)$ with respect to $\sin(x)$ is $-\tan(x)$.  It's discontinuous everywhere the sine is stationary (i.e., has zero derivative).  In general, is could also be discontinuous wherever the "with respect to function"'s derivative does not exist (although beware of removable singularities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth remembering that
$$  f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}  $$
is obtained after simplifying from
$$  f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{(x+h) - x}  \text{.}  $$
This is the rate of change of $f(x)$ with respect to the function $x \mapsto x$.

The most straightforward thing to do for the given problem is
\begin{align*}  \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}(x^2)} 
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{(x+h)^2 - (x^2)}  \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(x+h) - (x)}{x^2+2xh+h^2 - x^2}  \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h}{2xh+h^2}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2x}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

If the resulting derivatives exist, one can manipulate as
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}g(x)} 
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta g(x)}  \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{ \frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x} }{ \frac{ \Delta g(x)}{ \Delta x} }  \\
&= \frac{ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x} }{ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{ \Delta g(x)}{ \Delta x} }  \\
&= \frac{ f'(x) }{ g'(x) }  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you!